# ClassCastException when sending ArrayList of Parceleable objects

Tags: android, classcastexception, parcelable

Trying to send an ArrayList of user defined Parceleable objects to another activity.

In Activiy1:
`ArrayList<MyObject> uiObjects;` 
`//Code populating the arraylist`

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);` 
`Bundle bundle = new Bundle();`  
`bundle.putParcelableArrayList("objectList", uiObjects);` 
`intent.putExtras(bundle);` 
`startActivity(intent);`

In Activity2:
`Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();`

### `ArrayList<MyObject> uiObjects = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("objectList");`

Have a funny thing happening that I can’t figure out. I get a **ClassCastException** when I try iterating over uiObjects.
Using the ADT debugger I have ensured  ‘uiObjects’ is populated correctly in Activity1 and has 2 entries.
In Activity 2 however, one is my object, the other seems to be an Integer object (NO IDEA FROM WHERE).
Have looked up other posts on sending ArrayList of parcelable objects, but could not find a similar problem. Any insights as to what could be happening here ?

Comment: Could you please add your `Parcelable` implementation details?

Comment: @JuniKim, it was a problem with the `Parcelable` class, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You added one too many levels - you have your extras which contain a `Bundle` which contains your parcelable `ArrayList` hence what is returned when you call `bundle.getParcelableArrayList("objectList")` is a `Bundle`, not your `uiObjects` you expected. Instead use [putParcelableArrayListExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putParcelableArrayListExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E%29):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra ("objectList", uiObjects); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the extra level is unnecessary yes, it's not wrong however.
 As I do a:
`Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();` , in Activity2 before I call `getParcelableArrayList`.

Turns out I had a **bug** in my `Parceleable` class MyObject in the `writeToParcel` method.(I put in `dest.writeDouble(x)` instead of `dest.writeInt(x)` in one place). Fixing that seems to have worked and now it works just fine without making any changes to the code above.

I am still left wondering what actually made it give such a strange output though(one correct object and one `Integer` object in the returned `ArrayList`).